# Handeling a deleted record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to prevent my application to show error "Couldn't find ReceiptVoucher with id=53". Actually what i am doing i am opening two windows on first one i am listing all the record and on second window i am accessing particular record  suppose record with id 53. Now i have deleted that record from index page and again trying to delete it from second window which was opened earlier.

Here is my controller delete action:

```
def destroy
    @receipt_voucher = ReceiptVoucher.find(params[:id])
  if @receipt_voucher.blank?
  redirect_to(receipt_vouchers_url, :notice => "record not found")  
  else
    @receipt_voucher.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      @receipt_voucher.register_user_action(request.remote_ip, 'deleted')
      format.html { redirect_to(receipt_vouchers_url, :notice => "receipt voucher has been successfully deleted") }
    end
 end
```

end

How to handle this in controller. Any help would be thankful

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead: `@receipt_voucher = ReceiptVoucher.where(id: params[:id]).first`